# Improving the privacy of a casual Web user

Tags: web-browser, privacy, cookies, anonymity

I am interested in improving the privacy available to me as a casual internet user with a default browser.  I think that Tor is too slow and that the "Privacy Mode" in browsers isn't really practical.  I don't care about hiding the history from myself in fact I like having a local history.  I care about companies tracking me and profiting from it.  There are a lot of Firefox addons for "[Privacy and Security](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/privacy-security/)".  But which ones work,  and **why** do they work?

Interesting TED talk: [Tracking the Trackers](http://www.ted.com/talks/gary_kovacs_tracking_the_trackers.html).

Comment: Are you talking about web browsing or other Internet applications? Do you use a stable IP address for browsing? Do you keep cookies beyond session?

Comment: @curiousguy  browsing with a default browser. (I like firefox :)

Comment: "_"Privacy Mode" in browsers isn't really practical._" what is wrong with "private mode"?

Comment: curiousguy, private mode, if I recall correctly, just means local history/cookie/cache writes are cleared after use. It's for hiding your usage from other users on the same system.

Comment: @chao-mu "_curiousguy,_" please use "@curiousguy" "_private mode, if I recall correctly,_" you don't "_just means local history/cookie/cache writes are cleared after use. It's for hiding your usage from other users on the same system._" not only

Comment: I looked up the specifics. Firefox's "Private Browser" is only local writes. Particularly Visited pages, Form and Search Bar entries, Cookies, Passwords, Download List entries, and cache  (http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info). Chrome's is called "Incognito Mode" and is mostly the same thing https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464&p=cpn_incognito

Comment: @user5621 Do you have a stable IP address? Are you worried about your ISP spying on you?

Comment: @chao-mu "_"Private Browser" is only local writes_" that's wrong

Comment: @curiousguy I am mostly worried about the concerns brought up in "Tracking the Trackers."  I only care about remote threats,  I like having a browser history.

Comment: @user5621 Do you have a stable IP address? (third time)

Comment: @curiousguy  who cares? Like most users its mostly static,  but it can change.

Comment: @user5621 "_who cares?_" people who worry about being "tracked" care, or they should "_Like most users its mostly static, but it can change._" then your IP is "mostly" identifies you.

Comment: @curiousguy "... I don't care about hiding the history from myself in fact I like having a local history."  Also i hardly think this is a solution.

Comment: @curiousguy  I think the other comments ripped up this suggestion sufficiently.  In general chao-mu has the right idea.

Comment: Regardless as to whether your IP address is assigned statically or dynamically, your ISP has records of assignment which can easily be subpoenaed. Even if they did not record historical data, at least in my experience leases are typically held for long periods of time.

Comment: @chao-mu please use @ syntax when replying to a comment "_Regardless as to whether your IP address is assigned statically or dynamically, your ISP has records of assignment_" indeed "_which can easily be subpoenaed._" only with a legitimate legal excuse. "_at least in my experience leases are typically held for long periods of time._" There are many different cases: some ISP force a change every 24 hours; some will might you the same address forever unless you shut your modem for a few days or weeks; and others will give a different IP address at each modem reboot...

Comment: @user5621 "_I don't care about hiding the history from myself_" I understand, but you should also understand that private browsing mode is _not_ just about erasing your history on your PC.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a response to the title "improving the privacy of a casual internet user". As for individual plugins, you'll have to research and ask on an individual basis.

**Block ads**. This is an easy way to cut off forced interaction (e.g. image and iframe loads, popups, etc.) and prevents someone from getting paid for your clicks/views. If you are using Firefox, checkout [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/)

**Lie**. During registration processes, don't be afraid to omit or falsify your age, phone number, location, etc. Within the extent of the law, of course. If you want help, seek this [identity generator](http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/)

**Think** about what information you're disclosing. Remember that things like emails (both sent AND received) and search queries are fair game for the companies who provide the service.

**Keep informed**. If these topics matter to you, stay current with the [EFF](https://eff.org) and other whistle blowing groups.

Comment: +1 I like these solutions,  but I think more can be done.

Comment: @user5621, I agree. I turned it into a community wiki. Hopefully others can add onto it.

Answer (score 2):

For improving your privacy on webpages there are a number of things you can do. The trouble is, doing some of these things may break functionality. For example, if you disable all cookies then you may not be able to log into some websites.

Try not to give out personal information (such as your name or e-mail address) whenever possible. You can use disposible e-mail addresses when registering for sites you don't want e-mail from. You an ad-filter such as adblock plus. Also FireFox's BetterPrivacy add-on removes Flash based tracking cookies (this is what's discused in the TED talk). HTTPS Everywhere is another good add-on for Fire Fox which forces the browser to use a secure connection when possible.

That's the worst TED talk I've seen, he doesn't really explain anything. I usually really like TED talks.

Answer (score 2):

Some more suggestions:

- refrain from curiously clicking on *'interesting'* links/pictures
- if you're browsing logged on google for example, your profile is building up from everything you do, and stored somewhere.
- pay attention when registering to new sites, for what you're really registering
- have privacy in mind, whether you're registering on a new social network or creating a wish list on amazon
- don't bee too paranoid, just a little so you don't stop asking :)

A thorough [guide on Social  Networking Privacy](http://www.privacyrights.org/social-networking-privacy). Very good to read and ponder about.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to add to the other valid answers. You can configure these settings in any major browser, without plugins.

1. Block third party cookies. This is huge. Any time you see a Facebook "Like" button on a web page and you're not blocking third party cookies, you're being tracked. This is true for other widgets you may see. Most tracking is done via third party cookies, and it usually doesn't break (important) functionality on websites if you disable it.
2. Tell your browser to clear cookies when you exit. Any random cookies you pick up during one session will at least not be carried over to the next. The only downside is that you'll have to re-login to whatever services you use every time you open your browser. That should be trivial though, especially if you use a password manager like LastPass or 1Password.

Adblock Plus (Chrome and Firefox) is great because it prevents tracking elements from being downloaded in the first place. You can also configure it to block more than just ads as well.

Comment: If you have a stable IP address, does clearing cookies really helps?

Comment: IP addresses are not very useful for tracking individuals, as several individuals usually share the same IP address with NAT. The purpose of clearing cookies is to make it more difficult to analyze browsing behavior - "Phil owns this Facebook account, and he regularly visits websites X, Y, and Z"

Comment: For a home DSL line, "_several individuals_" is usually few persons from the same family. And even with cookies you have to face the same issue: many people sharing the same computer with just one account, **sharing one cookie jar**. "_"Phil owns this Facebook account, and he regularly visits websites X, Y, and Z"_" blocking G+/FB widgets in other sites would have the same effect.

Comment: True. Honestly, it's just an extra safeguard, not an essential. Over time cookies still build up even when blocking ads, "like" buttons, and third party cookies. If they're removed regularly, people will have a harder time tracking you. And while they can track you by IP address, it's a much more limited tracking mechanism than cookies.